# Scrapy Selectors with Basic HTML Pages no Output

Tags: scrapy

I'm having a tough time getting basic (very basic) html pages to output anything with the Scrapy spiders I'm using, hoping someone can put me on the right path.

Example of the html I'm trying to scrape:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../include/default.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="Author" content="Author">
<title>Article Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Month Day, Year</h3>

<hr size="1">

<h4>Article Title Here:</h4>

<p>paragraph 1, Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo</p>

<p>paragraph 2. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>

<p>paragraph 3, Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</p>

<p>closing, Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus </p>

<hr size="1">

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to scrape it with the following Scrapy spider

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from basic.items import BasicItem


class BasicSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "basiccrawl"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = [
"http://example.com/articles/",
]

def parse(self, response):
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
date = hxs.xpath('//h3')
title = hxs.xpath('//h4')
body = hxs.xpath('//p')
yield item
```

I assume I'm oversimplifying the xpath rules?

Answer (score 0):

If your spider is a subclass of CrawlSpider, it should not override the default parse callback (it is used internally by the CrawlSpider class). This is a bit confusing when you're getting started using Scrapy, it will probably be addressed in a future release.

In the code you posted, you are not using the CrawlSpider rules, so maybe you could ask yourself if you really need to inherit from CrawlSpider. You can go far inheriting only from `scrapy.Spider`.

The XPath expressions look fine, but the `.xpath()` method only returns a selector, you're missing the call to the `.extract()` method. Also, you probably don't need to instantiate the selector, if you're using Scrapy 0.24+ you can simply do:

```
def parse(self, response):
    date = response.xpath('//h3').extract()
    title = response.xpath('//h4').extract()
    body = response.xpath('//p').extract()
    yield item
```

You may want to go through the Scrapy tutorial I've written, that tries to get you started pretty quickly: http://hopefulramble.blogspot.com/2014/08/web-scraping-with-scrapy-first-steps_30.html

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the correct path, you need to use the method extract(), that method will return a list of element(s), if you are on begining of learning, maybe an slideshare that I create about Scrapy can help you :D
http://www.slideshare.net/franciscoyes/scrapy-42681497